# Using Probability and Optimization To "Reverse Engineer" a possible Dataset a Model was trained on?

Tags: probability, optimization

There is a field of modelling called "Survival Analysis" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Survival_analysis), in which the objective is to model the effect of different "characteristics" (e.g. medical measurements of patients such as height, age, weight, etc.) on the "time of some event" (e.g. death). Many models used in Survival Analysis are essentially a form of "Regression Models" (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Regression_analysis) - and of course, these models are built, train and fine tuned using some Optimization Algorithm (e.g. Newton-Raphson).

One of the most popular types of models used in Survival Analysis is called the "Cox Proportional-Hazards" Model (https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Proportional_hazards_model). As an example, here I have fit a Cox-PH Model to some medical dataset using the R programming language:

```
Call:
coxph(formula = Surv(time, status) ~ age + sex + ph.ecog, data = lung)

             coef exp(coef)  se(coef)      z        p
age      0.011067  1.011128  0.009267  1.194 0.232416
sex     -0.552612  0.575445  0.167739 -3.294 0.000986
ph.ecog  0.463728  1.589991  0.113577  4.083 4.45e-05

Likelihood ratio test=30.5  on 3 df, p=1.083e-06
n= 227, number of events= 164 
   (1 observation deleted due to missingness)
```

Based on these results, I can infer information such as:

- The number of observations
- The number of events
- The number of variables
- The estimate for the effect of each variable

**My Question:** Given this information, is it possible to simulate the covariate and response information for n = 227 such observations - such that if a similar Cox-PH model was fit to these newly simulated 227 observations, the resulting regression coefficients would approximately be equal to the original regression coefficients? Can I try to "guess" (and recreate) a plausible set of observations might have been observed based on the regression model coefficients?

This is where I thought that an Optimization Algorithm such as the Genetic Algorithm might be suitable. For example, below I tried to outline the pseudocode needed for such a problem:

Use an algorithm like the Genetic Algorithm (https://cran.r-project.org/web/packages/GA/vignettes/GA.html)

- Step 0 : Set some plausible ranges for the covariates (e.g. age between 20 - 80, sex either male or female, ph.ecog between 0 and 5 https://ecog-acrin.org/resources/ecog-performance-status/) . Specify distributions for each of these variables (e.g. age ~ lognormal, sex ~ binom, ph.ecog ~ multinomial) and specify parameters for each of these distributions (e.g. lognormal(mu1, sigma1), binom(p1), etc)
- Step 1: Set some plausible range and distribution for the Survival Times (e.g. Exponential Distribution with Lambda = 5)
- Step 2: Simulate 227 random observations and randomly censor 164 of these observations
- Step 3: Fit a Cox PH model to this simulated data and record performance measurements such as the coefficients, standard errors, p-values, likelihood ratio test, etc
- Step 4: Calculate the squared difference between these performance measurements from the model with the simulated dataset vs the performance measurements from the model with the actual dataset - and then sum all these squared differences.
- Step 5: Repeat Step 1 - Step 4 many times (e.g. 1000 times)
- Step 6: Repeat Step 0 - 5 many times
- Step 7: Use the Genetic Algorithm (or some other optimization algorithm) to find out which covariate ranges and covariate distributions bring you closest to the performance measurements of the original model. In other words, the "summed squared difference" is the Objective Function you will be attempting to optimize using the Genetic Algorithm.

I know this is a very abstract and roundabout way that might not have any mathematical validity - but I was curious to know if such an application of Optimization Algorithm might be logical? **In general, based only on the results of statistical/machine learning model - is it possible to simulate a plausible dataset that might have been used to build that model?**

Thanks!

Notes:

- I realize there are probably an infinite number of n = 227 samples that can be randomly simulated such that a Cox-PH Model produces the same regression coefficient estimates as above.
- I realize that its entirely possible that I happen to simulate a dataset in which all the ages are concentrated around 20-25 years old when in fact the real age of the participants in this dataset were senior citizens - but based on the results of the other simulated variables, the resulting Cox-PH model produced using this simulated data might coincidentally have the same performance results as the original model - thus rendering this approach useless.

Comment: I think a similar approach was used to generate multiple datasets with the same summary statistics here: https://www.autodesk.com/research/publications/same-stats-different-graphs

Comment: @ user51547 : thank you so much for this reference!